# What is melting integral I^2t

Tags: fuses

I am going to buy a fuse, but I am confused about what the purpose of I^2t is can someone please explain to me what it means.

Comment: Does \$I^2R\$ ring any bells, or Joule for that matter?

Comment: Yeah, power calculation

Comment: @SolarMike: No. Read what you've written and look at the formula.

Comment: @Transistor ok, misread it between I^(2t) and (I^2) * t

Comment: Yes, it's *times* time, not *over* time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two extremes for specifying the current carrying capability of a conductor.

a) Over a long time, so all heat is lost to the environment. The current will be given for some permitted temperature rise. Typically this is the temperature rating of the insulation.

b) Over a very short time, so short that no heat is lost to the environment. This is the so-called adiabatic case.

As the power generated in a conductor is \$I^2R\$, the heat energy deposited will be \$I^2Rt\$. For any given conductor, R will be constant, so the energy to some temperature, for the short time case is usually given as \$I^2t\$.

For a fuse, typical temperatures will be the 'guaranteed to still work', and 'guaranteed to break' or melting temperature.

When you're protecting something else that has a quoted survival \$I^2t\$, for instance a rectifier diode, you would want the rating of the diode to exceed the 'guaranteed to break' rating of the fuse, also known as the 'let through' energy.

Answer (score 6):

What they don't teach you in school is .... that a fuse also has a thermal **electrical-resistance coefficient** where R rises with temperature 1:10 near 3000'K and has a thermal mass, velocity and thermal resistance coefficient that are also dynamic in times < 0.1 second  so there are two power series trends for times.

In fuses  the \$I^2Rt\$ term is not accurate to determine fusing Energy because R rises with temperature but more importantly the cooling effects of longer times affects how much energy is needed

Due to the thermal time constant of the part, the self-cooling effect (Adiabatic threshold)  and non-linear thermal resistance (PTC effect) changes the power series coefficient.

Following example selected for 1A SMD 1206 fuse

[image]
Notice the exponent of energy changes due to log-log scale linear slope.

What does this mean?

For time > thermal time constant self-cooling demands more energy to raise resistance times current^2 to reach melting temperature of metal conductor and open fuse.

This is the steep curve for time > 0.1s.

Fuses are rated for the holding current within a certain temperature range and not the breaking current.

Comment: ah so that's why standardized wire has fusion current ratings for certain times.