# Maximum load capacitance and rating for fusing for bridge rectifier

Tags: diodes, capacitance, fuses, bridge-rectifier

I'm looking for a replacement for an old bridge rectifier and I've found one ([Vishay B80C1500G](https://www.vishay.com/docs/88501/b40c1500g.pdf)), but I'm curious about two parameters of the bridge rectifier:

1. Maximum load capacitance
2. Rating for fusing

As far as I know the more capacitance connected to the bridge, the more peak current occurs when the capacitor is being charged. Am I right? Other producers of bridge rectifiers don't specify this parameter in their datasheets. Does this parameter depend on *Peak forward surge current (IFRM)* and *maximum peak working voltage (VRWM)*?

How to understand the second parameter: rating for fusing? For what is this used?

[image: bridge rectifier datasheet]

Answer (score 1):

Gosh, I can't remember when, or if, I've ever seen limiting impedance specs on a rectifier, aside from vacuum tube types.  How...old fashioned?

Yes, I<sub>FRM</sub>, I<sub>FSM</sub> and I<sup>2</sup>t are equivalent ratings; meet or exceed these with a replacement and you're fine.

Excellent resources are available to explain fusing, see for example: 
[Eaton - Fuseology](https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electrical-circuit-protection/fuses/solution-center/bus-ele-tech-lib-rectifier-circuit-current-ratios.pdf) 
[Digi-Key - Fuse I2T Rating, Melting Point, and Interrupt Rating](https://forum.digikey.com/t/fuse-i2t-rating-melting-point-and-interrupt-rating/1271) 
[How do I use the I2T rating of a fuse?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/425989/how-do-i-use-the-i2t-rating-of-a-fuse)

In particular, the active phrase in the first link:

> Typically the semiconductor data sheet specifies a maximum I2
> t withstand for a semiconductor device. To offer short circuit protection to the semiconductor device, the fuse selected should have an I2t let-through less than the I2t withstand rating of the semiconductor device.

Comment: Thank you, very useful links. I'm still curious why "rate for FUSING" parameter is given for the BRIDGE RECTIFIER that it isn't even works as a fuse

Comment: Added in the edit.